# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

Tags: php

I'm stumped.  I'm doing a simple ajax form where the user will enter data and it will send the data to the server.

I've got the following code:

```
<?php
require("/mnt/library/configdb.php");        
require("/mnt/library/accessdb.php");

db_config_utility();
db_connect();

//Assign passed parameters
$submitDate = $_POST['submitDate'];
$mname      = $_POST['mname'];
$mid        = $_POST['mid'];
$coffice    = $_POST['coffice'];
$street     = $_POST['street'];
$city       = $_POST['city'];
$state      = $_POST['state'];
$zipcode    = $_POST['zipcode'];
$lat        = $_POST['lat'];
$lng        = $_POST['lng'];

//Setting up sql call
$sql="INSERT INTO manholes(
    submit_date,
    manhole_name, 
    manhole_id, 
    central_office, 
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zipcode,
    latitude,
    longitude
    )
    VALUES (
    '$submitDate',
    '$mname',
    '$mid',
    '$coffice',
    '$street',
    '$city',
    '$state',
    '$zipcode',
    '$lat',
    '$lng'
    )";

    echo("SQL: " . $sql);

//Making sql calls
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

The data is getting to the server correctly as the echo prints out correctly.  The server sends back a code `200` but does not place the data into the database. It also causes my ajax post to fall into the error function where the "`SyntaxError: Unexpected token S`".

If I remove the echo then the error thrown is "`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`"

Any advice on how to find what is causing the problem?

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: It's a JS error, not a PHP error. This should be pointed out.

Comment: You might want to research about SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PeeHaa this is just a proof of concept.  I will strengthen security once I build all the functionality. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: Yeah yeah. That's the first time ever somebody tells me that...

Comment: @PeeHaa Better? http://pastebin.com/2KyKVFHb ;)

Comment: Yes much better :-) Although I would prefer prepared statements, this should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `unexpected token S` is probably because you're `echo`ing text, which your ajax isn't expecting as a response. Removing it causes the other error because then you're not sending ANYTHING. You should check to see what your ajax function expects to receive (JSON?) and, after running your query, echo the correct response so your ajax knows it was successful.

Comment: That's it!  Stupid mistake on my part.  Ajax was expecting a json string and I was giving it just plaintext.

Comment: Cool. Also, a good note (which @PeeHaa mentioned above as well) is to make sure you protect against SQL injection attacks by wrapping your values in mysql escape functions before inserting them into the DB.